# Using kubectl how do I select resource based on some criteria?

Tags: kubectl

For example I can

```
$ kubectl get jobs --sort-by='.status.active'
```

which gives me a list of jobs.  Their status could be 0 and 1, so first come jobs the with zeros, then ones.  How do I *select* instead of sort?  For example, display only the ones that have status equal to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Formatting output

`kubectl` with `--sort-by` is more a way of [formatting output](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#sorting-list-objects) similar to how you can choose what fields to show in the output.

### Filter using Field Selectors

For **some pre-defined fields**, you can use [field selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) to filter your output.

Example

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running
```

### Labels and Selectors

The most common and customizable way to select subsets of resources is to conciously add *labels* to your resources. E.g. labels for app-name or team-name.

Then you can use [selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) to e.g. select a subset of the resources using `kubectl`

Example

```
kubectl get pods -l environment=production,tier=frontend
```

Comment: Initially I was trying to list completed jobs.  `kubectl` shows "Completed" in the Status column and I tried to `kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase=Completed`, which did not work.

I think what I lack is a way to discover what can I filter for -- what are the fields and what are their possible values.  I did `kubectl get pod my-pod -ojson` browsed through the output and realized that for a completed job one should use `status.phase=Succeeded`.